# mysql_query() returns something strange

Tags: php, mysql

I want to select one field (`MessageCounter`) from my database. Its type is `int(11)`. And I want to increase it.

Here's how I try to select it:

```
$q = "SELECT MessageCounter FROM " . TBL_USERS . " WHERE username = '$username'";
$result = mysql_query($q, $this->connection);
```

then I try to add `1` to it:

```
$messagecount = $result + 1;
$field = "MessageCounter";

$q = "UPDATE " . TBL_USERS . " SET " . $field . " = '$messagecount' WHERE username = '$username'";
return mysql_query($q, $this->connection);
```

And in the database it updates to `19`. If I add other number instead of `1`, say `3`, I get `21`. So the `$result` is somehow equal to `18`.
HOWEVER, if I try to update the database with the same unchanged result - it updates the field to `0`.

Does anyone have any idea what is happening?

Comment: dump the code line by line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot add 1 to `$result` - first you need to fetch the value out of it:

```
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
$messagecount = $row[0] + 1;`
```

BTW - at this stage of learning, you should abandon the deprecated `mysql_` functions and switch to mysqli or PDO instead. Do it right now.

Comment: Thank you, you can obviously see that I'm new to this. This really saved me

Answer (score 0):

`mysql_query()` returns a [Resource](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.resource.php) and not a normal variable on which you can perform addition operation.

and as [n-dru](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1477938/n-dru) suggested you should switch to [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) coz **mysql** extension is deprecated in PHP 5.5.0 and it's removed from PHP 7.0.0.

read [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)

Comment: Thanks, and yeah, I know about mysqli, but this is a one time work for university, where we have to "learn to work under customer's conditions" which includes working with an old PHP version and mysql.